D2RQ Mapping with MySQL Database Not Returning Results in SPARQL Queries
I'm trying to set up a D2RQ mapping to expose my MySQL database as RDF and query it using SPARQL. While my database connection seems to be working fine and I can retrieve data directly via SQL queries, my SPARQL queries are not returning any results. Here are the details of my setup:
Ontology (my_ontology.owl)
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://example.org/ontology#"
     xml:base="http://example.org/ontology"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://example.org/ontology"/>
    
    <!-- Class Genre -->
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/ontology#Genre"/>
    
    <!-- Subclasses of Genre -->
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/ontology#Person">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://example.org/ontology#Genre"/>
    </owl:Class>
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/ontology#Organization">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://example.org/ontology#Genre"/>
    </owl:Class>

    <!-- Class Knowledge -->
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/ontology#Knowledge"/>
    
    <!-- Property relatesTo -->
    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://example.org/ontology#relatesTo">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://example.org/ontology#Knowledge"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://example.org/ontology#Genre"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
</rdf:RDF>

Mapping File (mapping.ttl)
@prefix map: <#> .
@prefix db: <> .
@prefix vocab: <vocab/> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix d2rq: <http://www.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/suhl/bizer/D2RQ/0.1#> .
@prefix jdbc: <http://d2rq.org/terms/jdbc/> .

*# Load ontology*
map:ontology a d2rq:File;
    d2rq:dataStorage map:database;
    d2rq:fileName "C:/Users/samue/OneDrive/Desktop/my_ontology.owx".

map:database a d2rq:Database;
    d2rq:jdbcDriver "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    d2rq:jdbcDSN "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database";
    d2rq:username "root";
    d2rq:password "test123";
    jdbc:zeroDateTimeBehavior "convertToNull";
    jdbc:autoReconnect "true";
    .

*# Table genre mapping*
map:Genre a d2rq:ClassMap;
    d2rq:dataStorage map:database;
    d2rq:class <http://example.org/ontology#Genre>;
    d2rq:uriPattern "genre/@@genre.genre_id@@";
    d2rq:classDefinitionLabel "genre";
    d2rq:labelColumn "genre.genre_name".

*# Table knowledge mapping*
map:Knowledge a d2rq:ClassMap;
    d2rq:dataStorage map:database;
    d2rq:class <http://example.org/ontology#Knowledge>;
    d2rq:uriPattern "knowledge/@@knowledge.knowledge_id@@";
    d2rq:classDefinitionLabel "knowledge";
    d2rq:labelColumn "knowledge.label".

*# Table knowledge_to_genre mapping*
map:KnowledgeToGenre a d2rq:ClassMap;
    d2rq:dataStorage map:database;
    d2rq:class <http://example.org/ontology#KnowledgeToGenre>;
    d2rq:uriPattern "knowledge_to_genre/@@knowledge_to_genre.knowledge_id@@_@@knowledge_to_genre.genre_id@@".

*# Mapping for relatesTo property*
map:Knowledge_Genre_Relation a d2rq:PropertyBridge;
    d2rq:belongsToClassMap map:Knowledge;
    d2rq:property <http://example.org/ontology#relatesTo>;
    d2rq:refersToClassMap map:Genre;
    d2rq:join "knowledge.knowledge_id = knowledge_to_genre.knowledge_id";
    d2rq:join "genre.genre_id = knowledge_to_genre.genre_id".

SQL Query that Works
This SQL query correctly retrieves data from my database:
mySQL Query: (https://i.sstatic.net/p9bTIRfg.png)
SELECT * FROM knowledge
JOIN knowledge_to_genre ON knowledge.knowledge_id = knowledge_to_genre.knowledge_id
JOIN genre ON genre.genre_id = knowledge_to_genre.genre_id;
SPARQL Queries


I have tried several SPARQL queries but none of them return any results. Here are a few examples:
PREFIX ont: <http://example.org/ontology#>
SELECT ?knowledge ?genre
WHERE {
  ?knowledge ont:relatesTo ?genre .
}
LIMIT 10

Only a basic query (SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?p ?o WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 10) returns results, showing some data from the genre table.
The data mappings seem to be correct since the SQL query returns expected results.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I think D2rq has not been maintained in many years. A modern replacement for it is ontop:
https://github.com/ontop/ontop

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
